# Trace inequality on powers of non-negative matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If A is a non-negative $n \times n$ matrix, then I need to prove the following inequality for any k,m$\in \mathbb N$
   $$(tr(A^k))^m \le n^{m-1} tr(A^{km}).$$
I proved it for m=2 using Holder's inequality. But I don't know how to prove it for any m. Can any one help me??

Comment: Do you mean that $A$ has non-negative entries, or that $A$ is positive definite?

Comment: A is a matrix with non-negative entries.

Comment: I found the answer in the paper "Raphael Loewy & David London, A note on an inverse problem for nonnegative matrices,Linear and Multilinear Algebra,Volume 6, Issue 1, 1978"

Answer (score 0):

Let $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $A$ (with multiplicity). Since $\operatorname{tr} A^p = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^p$, your inequality is equivalent to
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^k\right)^m \leq n^{m-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^{mk}.
$$
Dividing by $n^m$, we obtain the equivalent form
$$
\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^k\right)^m \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^{mk}.
$$
Let $\Lambda$ be a random variable equal to each $\lambda_i$ with probability $1/n$. In terms of $\Lambda$, you want to show that
$$
E[\Lambda^k]^m \leq E[\Lambda^{km}].
$$
This follows from the convexity of $x \mapsto x^m$ (for $m \geq 1$) on $[0,\infty)$ (since $A$ is positive semidefinite, all eigenvalues are non-negative).

Comment: Can you please explain how does it follow from the convexity in the last step?

Comment: @LaRias Using Jensen's inequality.

Comment: Thank you. I think you have assumed A to be positive semidefinite, but the question is for a matrix with nonnegative entries.